# Possible to join as shapes with differing number of vertices

Tags: modeling, vertices, shape-keys

So I'm trying to join 2 different shapes together but Blender outputs an error saying it can't due to differing number of vertices. I've tried figuring out if there is anyway around this but haven't found any quick solutions for my use case other than either adding a lattice and manipulating the base shape to cover/fit the model shape, or pull single vertices to do the same which honestly doesn't look that great afterwards.

So my main question is, is there a way to get the base shape to follow my model shape to ease this process?

.. Or am I out of luck with that, and if so is there possibly an easier way than what I explained that I am doing earlier?

Comment: Please add some images to your question so that we can see what you're talking about! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Agree with John. The reason this isn't a button you can push, is that it will depend on topology,  case-by-case. Shape-keys are a simple linear interpolation between vertices with the same index.